What is the best way to show all errors on a paginated table?
I have data being displayed in a table that could be dozens of pages long. The user is only able to submit the data if the table is error free. It is not adequate to simply show a banner at the top indicating that there are errors or to just indicate the row with the error (e.g. If the error is on page 14/50 the user would have to click through each page until they find it). It would also be inadequate to show a modal with a list of errors because they would have to then find them in the table in order to correct them.
I think the best solution might be to have a button that, when clicked, filters the data to only show rows with errors. Maybe a 'Show all errors' toggle?
Is this is the best solution or has anyone come across something that makes more sense?
Thank you

How do you indicate that there is an error in the table? If you have a column that reflects the status of the data row, then you could simply use that column to filter the data without having to create a new button.

You need to present something like a table of contents for the errors. For example in a side banner (panel) or as non-modal, maybe dockable dialog. In this dialog you can present a table or buttons etc. with all sorts of information about the errors. Maybe even provide some bulk actions to fix multiple errors at once.
The idea of filtering to show only erroneous lines is a good approach, but it should not be the only one. You need to keep in mind that maybe the surrounding lines are needed to understand how to fix an error. Therefore the "table of content" idea outlined above to "jump" to the lines rather then filter them.
